# Join two colormaps in imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a plot using imshow(), but with a little custom colormap. For positive values I want to use e.q. "gnuplot" [colors](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) and for neagtive "cool". Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your problem looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997926/making-a-custom-colormap-using-matplotlib-in-python

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale -- note registering the colormap, which is maybe only mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
cmap, norm = mcolors.from_levels_and_colors(levels, colors)
```

to [construct a custom colormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors).

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

data = np.linspace(-10,5,20).reshape(5,4)

cmap = {name:plt.get_cmap(name) for name in ('gnuplot', 'cool')}
N = 50

vmin, vmax = (np.nextafter(min(data.min(), -1), -np.inf), 
              np.nextafter(max(data.max(), 1), np.inf))              # 1

levels = np.concatenate([np.linspace(vmin, 0, N, endpoint=False),
                         np.linspace(0, vmax, N+1, endpoint=True)])  # 2
colors = np.concatenate([cmap[name](np.linspace(0, 1, N)) 
                         for name in ('cool', 'gnuplot')])           # 3

cmap, norm = mcolors.from_levels_and_colors(levels, colors)

plt.imshow(data, cmap=cmap,
           norm=norm, 
           interpolation='nearest')
bar = plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

1. I wish the definition of `vmin, vmax` could be simpler. `min(data.min(), -1)`
   is used instead of `data.min()` in case `data` is positive. We need `vmin` to be
   negative for the custom colormap to be properly constructed. The `np.nextafter`
   nudges `vmin` down a little bit so the levels will encapsulate all the values in
   `data`. Without `np.nextafter`, `imshow` has a big white block when `data`
   equals `vmax`.
2. The colorbar levels go from `vmin` to `0` (exclusive), then `0` (inclusive)
   to `vmax`.
3. The colorbar colors are a concatenation of `N` colors sampled from `cool`,
   followed by `N` colors sampled from `gnuplot`. You can change `N` to control how many gradations of color from each underlying colormap you wish to have.