# Trying to plot temperature

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I was trying to plot the temperature of my Raspberry Pi and display that plot on a webpage. This works reasonably well. However, I was trying to color different regions of the plot according to the perceived risk (I'm not sure if they actually pose a risk to my Pi, but I wouldn't feel comfortable running it at e.g. 90°C).

I'm using this code to create the plot:

```
fig = plt.figure()

# color regions
plt.fill([0, 0, len(temps)-1, len(temps)-1], [80, 100, 100, 80], 'r', alpha=0.2, linestyle=None)
plt.fill([0, 0, len(temps)-1, len(temps)-1], [60, 80, 80, 60], 'y', alpha=0.2, linestyle=None)
plt.fill([0, 0, len(temps)-1, len(temps)-1], [0, 60, 60, 0], 'g', alpha=0.2, linestyle=None)

# modify axis
plt.axis([0, len(temps)-1, 0, 100])
plt.xticks([])

# plot and safe
plt.plot(temps, color='k')
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
plt.close(fig)
```

This creates the following plot:
[image: Example plot]

I don't like the "hard edges" of the regions, but I can't seem to find a way to let them "flow" into each other. Does anyone know how to solve this or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you mean `linewidth=0`?

Comment: Did you want to apply a gradient to the background?  http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/gradient_bar.html

Comment: @Artyer that's a good start, but it's still all green and then suddenly all yellow. I'd prefer a smooth transition.

Comment: @P-robot exactly! Can't see at first sight how to do this with 3 colours though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147997/how-to-change-a-linearsegmentedcolormap-to-a-different-distribution-of-color) (please show them some love too), it sounds like you want something along the lines of the following ...

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as clr

# Construct a colormap
cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('cmap for Dennis Hein', 
    [(0, '#ff0000'), (70/100., '#ffff00'), (100/100., '#00ff00')], N=64)

# Generate figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Limits
xmin, xmax = 0, 100
ymin, ymax = 0, 100

# Fake data
X = [[.0, .0], [1.0, 1.0]]

ax.imshow(X, interpolation='bicubic', cmap = cmap, 
    extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), alpha = 0.2)

ax.plot(np.random.normal(loc = 50, scale = 2, size = 101), c = 'k')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much.