# Manual set up colormap for color-bar Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, colorbar, colormap

I would like to create the following colormaps.

```
mycolorbar1 =  [dark-violet light-green dark-red dark-blue]

mycolorbar2 =  [dark-brown dark-red]
```

then I can use them in the following part of my code.

```
plt.tricontourf(triang1, Z1,v1,cmap=mycolorbar1, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=v1mi,vmax=v1ma))

plt.tricontourf(triang2, Z2,v2,cmap=mycolorbar2, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=v2mi,vmax=v2ma))
```

I really appreciate your help and assistance.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale?lq=1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the post my comment links to answers your question, it is probably over-complicated. There is a much more straightforward approach shown by Joe Kington in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997926/making-a-custom-colormap-using-matplotlib-in-python?lq=1) that uses `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()` to achieve custom colormaps.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

color_dict1 = {'dark_violet': '#880088',
               'light_green': '#00CC00',
               'dark_red':    '#AA0000',
               'dark_blue':   '#0000AA'}

color_dict2 = {'dark_brown': '#d95f0e',
               'dark_red':   '#e34a33'}


mycolorbar1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycolorbar1', [
    color_dict1['dark_violet'],
    color_dict1['light_green'],
    color_dict1['dark_red'],
    color_dict1['dark_blue']])

mycolorbar2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycolorbar2', [
    color_dict2['dark_brown'],
    color_dict2['dark_red']])
```

So that you can get plots like

[image]

Comment: Really appreciated, can you please let me know where should I obtain the color coding such the ones you mentioned?
    'dark_violet': '#880088'

Comment: I found the references. Thanks again.
http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html

Comment: That's a good reference, but for all things color-related in matplotlib I prefer http://colorbrewer2.org/