# Custom cmap with levels and colors array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to create a custom cmap for use in Python 3.5 using an array of levels and an array of colors.

The levels array is: levels = `[-4, 0 ,0, .25, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]`

and the colors are:

```
colors=[
(0,0,0),
(.8627,.8627, .8627),
(.5569,.4745,.7098),
(.0392,.0392, .6078),
(.2667,.9725,.8314),
(.3529,.8667,.3843),
(1,1,.3922),
(.8627,.0392,.0196),
(.6863,0,0),
(.9412, .4706,.7059),
(1,1,1),
    (.5686,.1765,.5882)  
    ]
```

I've tried using info from this page [Making a custom colormap using matplotlib in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997926/making-a-custom-colormap-using-matplotlib-in-python)

and subsequently

`vmax = 8.0`

```
zdr = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', [(-4 / vmax, (0,0,0)), (0 / vmax, (.8627,.8627, .8627)), (0 / vmax, (.5569,.4745,.7098)), (.25 / vmax, (.0392,.0392, .6078)), 
                                               (1 / vmax, (.2667,.9725,.8314)), (1.5 / vmax, (.3529,.8667,.3843)), (2 / vmax, (1,1,.3922)), (3 / vmax, (.8627,.0392,.0196)), 
                                               (4 / vmax, (.6863,0,0)), (5 / vmax, (.9412, .4706,.7059)), (6 / vmax, (1,1,1)), (8 / vmax, (.5686,.1765,.5882))])
```

but still receive the following error.

`ValueError: data mapping points must start with x=0. and end with x=1`

Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error message tells you that your list needs to provide values between x=0 and x=1. In your code `-4/vmax < 0`. So essentially that means that you need to normalize your range of `[vmin=-4, vmax=8]` into the interval `[0,1]`, e.g. by calculating `(x-vmin)/(vmax-vmin)`.