# Matplotlib Smooth Grey-Red Color Bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am struggling to create the color bar that I want in matplotlib. Ideally it would look like more like this (lows are greys, highs are bright red:

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |

However I am getting the following:

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |

```py
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

colors_top = cm.get_cmap('Greys_r', 128)
colors_bot = cm.get_cmap('Reds', 128)
cmap_grey_red = ListedColormap(
    np.vstack((
        colors_top(np.linspace(0, 1, 128)),
        colors_bot(np.linspace(0, 1, 128))
    )), name='GreyRed'
)
```

How can I correct this color bar?

Comment: This appears related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25996834/2864250

Comment: @dubbbdan yes somewhat related. `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("GreyRed",['grey', "r"])` is closer, still not as nice as I would like it though... thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever approach you choose, you will still have to map the colors to whatever scale the color bar is displaying using the `norm` argument.  Here is what I could quickly come up with:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

x,y,c = zip(*np.random.rand(30,3)*4-2)

cvals  = [-2., 0,  2]
colors = ["dimgray","salmon","red"]

norm=plt.Normalize(min(cvals),max(cvals))
tuples = list(zip(map(norm,cvals), colors))
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", tuples)

plt.scatter(x,y,c=c, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The color ramp you provided is diverging (e.g., white in the middle), If you want a smoother transition, you could just develop a color map with three colors.