# Downsampling Velocity Information in a Quiver Plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I have two arrays (vel_y,vel_z) representing velocities in the y and z directions, respectively, that are both shaped as (512,512) that I am attempting to represent using a quiver plot.
Here is how I plotted the quiver:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,512,num=512)
[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
ax.quiver(X,Y,vel_y,vel_z,np.arctan2(vel_z,vel_y),pivot='mid',units='x',scale=2)
```

The arctan2() call is so that different orientations are colored differently as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026718/different-colours-for-arrows-in-quiver-plot).
Obviously plotting all 512<sup>2</sup> of these arrows makes for a jumbled and difficult to parse plot, which you can see here:
[Quiver Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dfbm.png).

---

I was wondering if there was a better way to scale/represent the arrows so that it is more readable?

**However**, the main question I have is how I could 'downsample' this velocity information to go from plotting 512<sup>2</sup> arrows to 100<sup>2</sup> for example. Would this require interpolation between points where the velocity is defined?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this is simply to take one point over N in each vectors given to quiver.

For a given `np.array`, you can do this using the following syntax: `a[::N]`. If you have multiple dimensions, repeat this in each dimension (you can give different slip for each dimension): `a[::N1, ::N2]`.

In your case:

```
N1 = 5
N2 = 5
ax.quiver(X[::N1, ::N2], Y[::N1, ::N2], vel_y[::N1, ::N2], vel_z[::N1, ::N2], np.arctan2(vel_z,vel_y)[::N1, ::N2], pivot='mid',units='x',scale=2)
```

You don't need interpolation, unless you want to plot velocities at points not defined in the grid where you have your measurements/simulations/whatever.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you! I was thinking it would be much more complicated but that makes sense.

Comment: Unless you need more help, you may want to accept the answer to close the topic.