# Barplot colored according a colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

First of all, I'm pretty new to colors in Matplotlib or Seaborn. My purpose is to create a barplot with bars coloured according to a custom palette. Something like this, but with my custom palette (see below, a palette with red, orange, green and blue):

[image: barplot]

I have created my custom sequential palette using the `LinearSegmentedColormap` method, but I'm not able to use it in a simple `plt.barplot()`. Sure it's not difficult, but I can't see the way. I created the palette using the function below, got from this thread: [Create own colormap using matplotlib and plot color scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale)

```
def make_colormap(seq):
"""Return a LinearSegmentedColormap
seq: a sequence of floats and RGB-tuples. The floats should be increasing
and in the interval (0,1).
"""
seq = [(None,) * 3, 0.0] + list(seq) + [1.0, (None,) * 3]
cdict = {'red': [], 'green': [], 'blue': []}
for i, item in enumerate(seq):
    if isinstance(item, float):
        r1, g1, b1 = seq[i - 1]
        r2, g2, b2 = seq[i + 1]
        cdict['red'].append([item, r1, r2])
        cdict['green'].append([item, g1, g2])
        cdict['blue'].append([item, b1, b2])

return mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap('CustomMap', cdict)

#main#
c = mcolors.ColorConverter().to_rgb
rvb = make_colormap(
[c('red'), 0.125, c('red'), c('orange'), 0.25, c('orange'),c('green'),0.5, c('green'),0.7, c('green'), c('blue'), 0.75, c('blue')])

N = 1000
array_dg = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(N, 2))
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 5, size=(N,))
plt.scatter(array_dg[:, 0], array_dg[:, 1], c=colors, cmap=rvb)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

That returns this plot:

[image: plot palette ok]

As far as I can understand, I can't use a colormap (object type from `LinearSegmentedColormap()`? ) for barplots, but colormap is the unique way I have achieved a custom sequential palette.

In summary, I want to **apply the colormap of the second plot (the scatterplot) to the first plot (the barplot)**. For now I can't do it because the `barplot()` function has not an argument that accepts a `LinearSegmentedColormap` object type.

I'm probably making it harder than it really is, so I would appreciate any cleaner or more correct way.

Comment: I do not see the problem at all. The code is working fine. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Sorry, probably did not explain my problem enough. I want to know how to use this colormap in a barplot, like "plt.barplot(x, y, color= "my_custom_colormap"). As you can see in the first comment, the palette works fine in the scatter plot ( plt.scatter(...c = colors, cmap = rvb) ). The problem is that in the barplot function there isn't an argument like "cmap".

Comment: In your code you have a scatterplot, not a barplot. Which quantity would you like the colors in the barplot to represent? Please [edit] your question to reflect the problem itself, not something that is actually working fine.

Comment: your indentation is all wrong. please fix it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To obtain a barplot with the bars colored according to a colormap you can use the `color` argument of `bar(x,y, color=colors)`, where `colors` is a list of length number of bars, containing all the colors. I.e. the `i`th entry in that list is the color for the `i`th bar.
In order to create this list from the colormap, you need to call the colormap with the respective value.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

clist = [(0, "red"), (0.125, "red"), (0.25, "orange"), (0.5, "green"), 
         (0.7, "green"), (0.75, "blue"), (1, "blue")]
rvb = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", clist)

N = 60
x = np.arange(N).astype(float)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 5, size=(N,))

plt.bar(x,y, color=rvb(x/N))
plt.show()
```

Comment: how do we add the colorbar?

Comment: For a colorbar, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51205723/4124317

Answer (score 10):

Seaborn `barplot` is great for this, [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
ax = sns.barplot("size", y="total_bill", data=tips, palette="Blues_d")
```