# Pandas subplots loses data when sharex=True (bug?) - added data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Using a data array and filtering in certain manner, if plotting without `sharex=True`, the plots seems complete. Some data may be zero (or no data available), where no bar appears in this subplot (missing on the x-axis! - may be if `sharex=False`, but would be nicer if shown correctly; or could be switched on). - When I set `sharex=True` (nothing else is changed in my code!!), I do expect all information in all subplots, even if the value of certain data is zero. But instead of this, I do get just a single bar instead of my expected plots. My assumption is, that only the common bars (non zero) in all the plots are shown.

Is there any way to have all x-parameters shown in all subplots using the same x-axis ??

Here is my code:

```
% matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

ds1 = pd.DataFrame({ "Q2" : [1,2,1,0,2,1,6,4,2,1,2,1,3,2,1,5,1,2,1], 
    "Q3" : [1,5,1,2,2,5,7,1,1,1,5,1,4,2,5,4,1,1,1]})
ds2 = pd.DataFrame({ "Q2" : [1,5,1,4,2,1,5,1,2,1,2,1,3,2,3,4,1,2,1],  
    "Q3" : [3,5,1,2,2,1,4,1,3,1,3,1,4,4,1,3,1,3,1]})
ds3 = pd.DataFrame({ "Q2" : [1,1,2,5,3,3,4,4,2,1,2,1,3,2,3,5,3,4,1],  
    "Q3" : [3,2,1,0,2,1,5,1,2,1,2,1,5,2,1,0,1,2,1]})

ds = [ds1, ds2, ds3]

def func():    
    fig, axes = plot.subplots(len(ds), 5, figsize=(20, 20), sharex=True, sharey=True)
    for k, d in enumerate(ds):
        filter =  [ (d["Q2"] == 1),
                (d["Q2"] == 2),
                (d["Q2"] == 3),
                (d["Q2"] == 4),
                (d["Q2"] == 5)]

        for i, f in enumerate(filter):
            a = d[filter[i]].groupby(list(ds1)[1]).size()/len(d[filter[i]])
            a.plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[k][i])
```

(Python 3.7, fresh installation)
[Edit] - just started to think about seaborn instead, this may have other behavior or possibilities. Because I am new to seaborn, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I commented on your previous question to use `axes[k][i].bar(a.index, a.values)`, which would result in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4C0A.png). In how far is this, or is this not what you're after?

Comment: @Ernest - your image is closer, but I could not reproduce - a.plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[k][i]).bar(a.index, a.values) or a.plot.bar(a.index, a.values, ax = axes[k][i]) does not work.  Also without the sharex=True I do get colored bars. Could you please explicate your changes.

Comment: The image is produced by replacing the line `a.plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[k][i])` from your code by `axes[k][i].bar(a.index, a.values)`.

Comment: @Ernest - oh yes. This gives some more bars in the chart, but still an uglier workaraound instead of setting the sharex to false (because the colors to identify the different values in the x-axes fail).

Comment: I also reported to the pandas groop - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24974 - they may be able to solve the issue or to fix the bug.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. This is not a bug. Issue trackers are not meant for user support usually. The reason it doesn't work with pandas is simply that pandas bar plots are categorical. If you need colored bars, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539105/y-values-in-a-bar-plot-according-to-a-colormap). For that you will need to not filter the data, but have `0` or `nan` at the missing data.