# Scatter plot Data from a Matrix in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matrix looking like:

```
50    3    1
100   3    1
150   3    0
...
100   15   0
150   15   0
```

Now I want to use a scatter plot to plot it. Where:

```
Matrix[:][0] = X-Values  #  For demonstration used the ':' operator from Matlab which means it includes all values.
Matrix[:][1] = Y-Values
Matrix[:][2] = color where 0 = blue & 1 = yellow
```

For example. The first point would be:

```
Matrix[0][0] = 50 as X-Value of first point
Matrix[0][1] = 3 as Y-Value of first point
Matrix[0][2] = 1 as color (yellow) of first point
```

I already tried the following

```
plt.scatter(Matrix[0], Matrix[1]) # didn't worked. Had only like 4 scatter points instead of over 100
plt.scatter(Matrix[:][0], Matrix[:][1]) # Same issue
for i in range(len(Matrix)):
    plt.scatter(Matrix[i][0], Matrix[i][1], c=Matrix[i][2]) # worked, but is pretty slow and all points were black instead of colored
```

My Matrix is created by:

```
w, h = len(list_of_dfs), 3) 
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(h)] for y in range(w)]
# And then filled like
Matrix[0][0] = 50 ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty? What have you tried? How much of `matplotlib` do you already know? This question needs more context, especially some work done by you already.

Comment: `plt.scatter(Matrix[0], Matrix[1], c=Matrix[2])` ?

Comment: @HarvIpan It was the first thing I tried. I didn't worked for me I only get like 4 entries in my scatter plot. But my matrix has over 100 rows.

Comment: @ChrizZlyBear, did you check it for overlapping?

Comment: @HarvIpan Yes. I added some information and an (inefficient) way where it partly works. Maybe these information will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matrix[:][0]` gives you the first row of the array.

```
Matrix[:][0] == (Matrix[:])[0] == Matrix[0]
```

Assuming that `Matrix` is a numpy array, you need to index it like

```
Matrix[:,0]
```

to get the first column out. If it isn't a numpy array, you can make it one via `Matrix = numpy.array(Matrix)`.

Hence,

```
plt.scatter(Matrix[:,0], Matrix[:,1], c=Matrix[:,2])
```

Comment: I had a matrix created by myself. Now I switched to numpy, which is clearer and faster (and it works).
Thanks. 
Could you aswell tell me how I can change the color to blue and yellow? I get black and yellow.

Comment: In case none of [the colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) that ship with matplotlib works for you you may use your own colormap as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46778420/4124317).