# How to plot a heat-map in python with specific colors for specific values

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

My dataset is an 2D-array which contains specific numbers. The only numbers present in it are **0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9,14,16,17,26,33,34,35**. I want to associate specific colors with specific values. For eg - **( #FFFFFF with 0)**, **(#000000 with 1)**, **(#1a0000 with 2)** ... **(#660066 with 35)** .

I was using seaborn for this task but I have not been able to modify it as per my specific requirement.

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: This may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale