# Python Basemap: Use a color table from an rgb file instead of the predefined Matplotlib color tables

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, colormap

I have a file `GMT_panoply.rgb` with the following color table:

```
ncolors= 16
# r g b
0.015686 0.054902 0.847059
0.125490 0.313725 1.000000
0.254902 0.588235 1.000000
0.427451 0.756863 1.000000
0.525490 0.850980 1.000000
0.611765 0.933333 1.000000
0.686275 0.960784 1.000000
0.807843 1.000000 1.000000
1.000000 0.996078 0.278431
1.000000 0.921569 0.000000
1.000000 0.768627 0.000000
1.000000 0.564706 0.000000
1.000000 0.282353 0.000000
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.835294 0.000000 0.000000
0.619608 0.000000 0.000000
```

When I use python Basemap for plotting, I generally do the following:

```
ax.map.pcolor(x,y,np.squeeze(val), cmap='jet')
```

How to do this plotting by replacing `jet` with the file `GMT_panoply.rgb` that has my color table?

Comment: Perhaps this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale) may contain helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

In case Jacob K's answer is not sufficient, my CMasher package allows one to import their own colormaps into Python with a single function (https://cmasher.readthedocs.io/user/usage.html#custom-colormaps).