# How to make black and white and red gradient image in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

can you tell me is it possible to make this gradient image in python for example with matplotlib contour plot (like the image of the centre of our galaxy?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNDRl.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking for a colormap using custom colors ?

Comment: I only want to use black, whtie and red colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom colormap using `LinearSegmentedColormap`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black","red","white"])
plt.imshow(img, cmap = cmap)
```