# Select part of the colormap plotting terrain

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, visualization, tiff

#### Data

- the .tif data **DEM** was the altitude value represent the hypsography of one administrative division. I upload it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQdDRERG02ZVJya00/view?usp=sharing)
- The area besides the division I don't want to show them on the plot.

#### My aim

Plotting the hypsography of this division using `plt.pcolormesh`(*PS: I found out with reading .tif, `plt.imshow()` was way faster than `pcolormesh`. And I don't know Why*).

Here I show one example which I clipped from internet.

http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-10/56951530.jpg

#### My attempt

```
### Using GDAL to read the .tif data
from osgeo import gdal
### Read the .tif
pathToRaster = r'./dem.tif'
raster = gdal.Open(pathToRaster,  gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
dem = raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
dem = dem[::-1]       

### Mask the outside value
dem_mask = np.ma.masked_less(dem,0)
plt.pcolormesh(dem_mask,cmap =plt.cm.terrain)
```

#### Result

http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-10/45669007.jpg

#### Problem

In my research division, this area didn't contain the Sea/Ocean which are plotted by `blue` above.

But I want to use the `plt.cm.terrain` as my `pcolormesh`'s colormap because it fit the situation.

So, I want to **remove the blue part of the colormap**, and start the terrain using `green` representing the plain.

Comment: could you adjust the `vmin` of the `pcolormesh`? Try making it significantly lower than the minimum of your data

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two solutions right now.

#### 1. Using `vmin` to set a smaller beginning.

```
>print dem_mask.min()
>print dem_mask.max()
output: 20
        2271
## Set vmin value far smaller than 20
plt.pcolormesh(dem_mask,cmap =plt.cm.terrain,vmin = -800)
```

#### 2. Extract a subset of a colormap referencing to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926031/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-colormap-as-a-new-colormap-in-matplotlib)

```
 import matplotlib.colors as colors
 def truncate_colormap(cmap, minval=0.0, maxval=1.0, n=100):
     new_cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
           'trunc({n},{a:.2f},{b:.2f})'.format(n=cmap.name, a=minval, b=maxval),
            cmap(np.linspace(minval, maxval, n)))
     return new_cmap    

 cmap = plt.get_cmap('terrain')
 new_cmap = truncate_colormap(cmap, 0.25, 0.9)
 plt.pcolormesh(dem_mask,cmap =new_cmap,)
```

#### Result

http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-11/96590416.jpg