# Search for a colormap with similarities to CMRmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for the following colormap in matplotlib, which I saw in a paper:
[image]

At first I thought it was a section of the `CMRmap` colormap.

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('CMRmap')
new_cmap = truncate_colormap(cmap, 0.0, 0.75) #(https://stackoverflow.com/a/18926541/7559986)
```

However, the following came out when I extract a subset of it, which looks a bit different (especially the yellow):

[image]

Does anyone know how I get to the upper colormap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colormap you show looks like it's just an interpolation between black, blue, red and yellow. This would be created via

```
matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "blue", "red", "yellow"])
```

However, I would not recommend using such colormap. Instead use any of `"viridis"`, `"magma"`, `"plasma"` or `"inferno"`. Those are perceptually uniform and hence do not create unwanted artifacts.

Below is a comparisson between the interpolated map and `"magma"`. As you can see the interpolated map creates "rings", such that the viewer would surely misinterprete the shape that is plotted.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

x = np.linspace(-2,2, 101)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = np.exp(-X**2-Y**2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

im1 = ax1.imshow(Z, cmap="magma")


cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "blue", "red", "yellow"])
im2 = ax2.imshow(Z, cmap=cmap)

fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1, orientation="horizontal")
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2, orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Further reading

- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html
- https://bids.github.io/colormap/ on why it's bad to use such non-uniform maps.