# How to get part of a colormap

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

I'm plotting some curves from a dataframe "self.data" in a class. Each column of the dataframe is a curve and the column name is written at the end of the line.

I made this program to do so:

```
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('brg', len(self.data.columns)+1)

for i in range(len(self.data.columns)): #plot curves and add legend
        self.courbe.plot(self.data[self.data.columns[i]],c=cmap(i))

        angle=20
        self.courbe.annotate(self.data.columns[i], 
                    xy= (max(self.data.index),self.data.at[max(self.data.index),self.data.columns[i]]),
                    textcoords='offset points',
                    xytext=(2, 0),
                    va='bottom',
                    rotation=angle,c=cmap(i))
```

So i used the "brg" colormap but i'd like to use only a part of this color map ( for example removing the light green part).

I tried some proposed solutions on stackoverflow like [how to extract a subset of a colormap as a new colormap in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926031/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-colormap-as-a-new-colormap-in-matplotlib) but all curves were in the same color. Do someone knows another way to do that?

Thanks and have a good day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`norm`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) is used to map a range of numbers towards the range 0..1 needed by the colormap.  We can create a special norm to get the desired effect.

A norm depends on a vmin, the lowest index, and a vmax, the highest index. `vmin` would be mapped to 0 and vmax to 1.

Choosing an upper and lower color (each between 0 and 1), for example upper=0.9 to stop at the light greens in [bgr](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). And lower=0 to get all the colors up to the dark blue.

A formula finds the vmin and vmax which would map index `i=0` to the lower_color and index `i=num_colors-1` to the upper_color. The formula follows from the unique linear equation which maps:

- `0` to `lower_color`
- `num_colors - 1` to `upper_color`
- `vmin` to `0`
- `vmax` to `1`

You find the color index for a value `i=0..num_colors-1` as `norm(i)` and the corresponding color as `cmap(norm(i))`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('brg')

# between 0 and 1, 0 for the leftmost color of the range, 1 for the rightmost, upper > lower
upper_color = 0.8
lower_color = 0.3
num_colors =  20 # len(self.data.columns)
factor = (num_colors - 1)/(upper_color - lower_color)
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-lower_color*factor, vmax=(1 - lower_color)*factor)

for i in range(num_colors):
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, i], c=cmap(norm(i)))

plt.show()
```

An example with the `brg` map and choosing colors between 0.3 and 0.8, just to show how it works. For reference, there is a colorbar with the same limits applied. And a full colorbar for `brg`.

[image: example plot]

The colorbars were generated as follows:

```py
c_map_ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.84, 0.1, 0.02, 0.8])
mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(c_map_ax, cmap=cmap, orientation='vertical')
c_map_ax.axes.set_ylim(lower_color, upper_color)
c_map_ax2 = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.92, 0.1, 0.02, 0.8])
mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(c_map_ax2, cmap=cmap, orientation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
```

Comment: I don't understand the factor in use here. And I think with `lower_color=0.3` one would expect the bottom line to be purple, not the top one.

Answer (score 4):

The factor in use by the other answer may be a little unintuitive; hence here is the same, just without any norm or factor. You'd still choose a lower and upper value between 0 and 1 and just obtain the colors within that range from the colormap. Then loop over them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('brg')

# between 0 and 1, 0 for the leftmost color of the range, 1 for the rightmost, upper > lower
upper_color = 0.8
lower_color = 0.3
num_colors =  20 # len(self.data.columns)
colors = cmap(np.linspace(lower_color, upper_color, num_colors))

for i, color in enumerate(colors):
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, i], color=color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. For this solution you don't need the restriction that upper > lower. You can even use it to simply reverse the array of colors.