# How to "cut" the unwanted part of a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Say you create an image with `imshow` like this:

```
plt.set_cmap('viridis')
im=plt.imshow(mydata, interpolation='nearest',origin='lower')
plt.title('mymap')
cbar=plt.colorbar()
a=round(mydata.max(),0)
cbar.set_ticks([17,23,a])
cbar.set_ticklabels([17,23,a])
```

Say you have a continuous-like dataset where most values are 0, but then there's a jump leading to the range of highest values.

**How do you "cut" the colorbar to make sure it starts from `mydata.min()=17`, ends at `mydata.max()=27`, without changing the colors in the image?**

---

I don't want this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard solution for limiting the color range in a colorbar, because the shown colors are usually directly linked to the colors in the image.

The solution would therefore be to create a colorbar, which is independent on the image, filled with a different colormap. This additional colormap can be taken from the original one by cutting out the respective portion one needs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

# some data between 0 and 27
image = np.random.rand(30,60)*27
image[:,30:] = np.sort(image[:,30:].flatten()).reshape(30,30)


plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
im=plt.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest',origin='lower', cmap = cmap)
plt.title('mymap')


a=round(image.max(),0)

vmin=17  #minimum value to show on colobar
vmax = a #maximum value to show on colobar
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax =vmax)
#generate colors from original colormap in the range equivalent to [vmin, vamx] 
colors = cmap(np.linspace(1.-(vmax-vmin)/float(vmax), 1, cmap.N))
# Create a new colormap from those colors
color_map = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('cut_jet', colors)

# create some axes to put the colorbar to
cax, _  = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(plt.gca())
cbar = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=color_map, norm=norm,)

cbar.set_ticks([17,23,a])
cbar.set_ticklabels([17,23,a])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one, but (trivial question warning) would like to get rid of the right hand side portion. But I guess I can't as it is the "baseline" for which the correct colorbar is created.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(mydata,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[17,23,a])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["add your label names"])

plt.show()
```

also see: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html

Comment: It does not work as I expected. It leaves the bar exactly as you see it in the example.

Comment: @d.griner Your solution does not meet the requirement written in bold letters in the question.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. I thought the objective was to have 17 to be dark blue and 27 to be yellow.