# limit range of colorbar on bar graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, colorbar

I've been attempting to limit the range on the colorbar function in matplotlib. For whatever reason, I cannot use the clim function. Ideally I would like 80 and 20 to be the max values of the colorbar, and all values above or below those values to be a single dark blue/red, and the entire colorbar to be fit within the range of 20 and 80.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
Gpercent=40
xGpercent = 60
SCFpercent = 55
CFpercent = 45
Analytics = ['GF%','xGF%','SCF%','CF%']
AnalyticsValues = [Gpercent,xGpercent,SCFpercent,CFpercent]
AnalyticsValues = [float(val) for val in AnalyticsValues]
data_height_normalized = [x / 100 for x in AnalyticsValues]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 4))
#my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu')
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm_r')
colors = my_cmap(data_height_normalized)

rects = ax.bar(Analytics, AnalyticsValues, color=colors)

sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(0,100))

plt.ylim(0, 100)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100.8, 10))
plt.title('bob' + (" On Ice 5v5 Impact"))
plt.xlabel('Analytical Metric')
plt.ylabel('%')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
plt.show()
```

[The plot comes out as follows. I'd like the colorbar to be more defined in a shorter range, while still showing the % from 0-100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ11u.png)

Answer (score 1):

The intent of your question is to add an upper and lower limit to the color bar only. I would like to set the lower limit to 20 and the upper limit to 80. I will answer with the understanding that
The gist of the code is to create a new colormap from the defined colormap using LinearSegmentedColormap with the upper and lower color range.
My answer was modified from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982050/matplotlib-how-to-cut-the-unwanted-part-of-a-colorbar) to fit your assignment.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap # add
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

Gpercent=40
xGpercent = 60
SCFpercent = 55
CFpercent = 45
Analytics = ['GF%','xGF%','SCF%','CF%']
AnalyticsValues = [Gpercent,xGpercent,SCFpercent,CFpercent]
AnalyticsValues = [float(val) for val in AnalyticsValues]
data_height_normalized = [x / 100 for x in AnalyticsValues]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 4))
#my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu')
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm_r')
colors = my_cmap(data_height_normalized)

rects = ax.bar(Analytics, AnalyticsValues, color=colors)

# update
vmin,vmax = 20,80
colors2 = my_cmap(np.linspace(1.-(vmax-vmin)/float(vmax), 1, my_cmap.N))
color_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('cut_coolwarm', colors2)

sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=color_map, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin, vmax))

plt.ylim(0, 100)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100.8, 10))
plt.title('bob' + (" On Ice 5v5 Impact"))
plt.xlabel('Analytical Metric')
plt.ylabel('%')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
plt.show()
```

[image]