# How to hide part of the colorbar after plotting it in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I have the following colorbar in matplotlib that I use to plot certain colormap.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYfga.png)

I wonder if it is possible to clip the negative part without changing the color scheme?

I tried to use `set_clim(vmin, vmax)`, but this changes the color scheme above, which I don't want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change colorbar limits without changing the values of the data it represents in scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257255/change-colorbar-limits-without-changing-the-values-of-the-data-it-represents-in)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.